# Model files and DB interaction in Laravel/Spark

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-spark

I have been using Laravel for quite few months. I switched to Spark for my new project and got few questions.

1. Where are the Model files in Spark? (I used to have my Model files in app/Model in Laravel)
2. I could not find logic where the DB connection and select or other mySql queries happens? Please help me find those.
3. How to completely disable the Subscription/Billing related elements from front-end. As I don't have to charge my Users
4. Do we have full documentation which covers all Spark concepts. I checked the basic videos of spark but I am searching for detailed documentation.

Please note that I freshly installed Spark so did not have any code that I tried  to clear my doubts mentioned above.

Comment: What version of Laravel were you using before? And if you're not going to use the subscription/billing parts of Spark, what use it at all? Spark was made from the ground up with the subscription model in mind.

Comment: https://spark.laravel.com/docs/1.0/customization#model-classes

Comment: We have plan to include subscription in future. We want to show our website without subscription in first release. Thats our requirement and design.

I am using Laravel 5.1